# How can I use async / await functions?

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have a function as follows:

```
function getMessages(){
     this.removeListener = myFirestore
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(this.groupChatId)
          .collection(this.groupChatId)
          .onSnapshot(
            snapshot => {
              snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                if (change.type === 'added') {
                  this.listMessage.push(change.doc.data())
                }
              })
            },
            err => {
              console.log(err)
            }
          )
          return this.renderMessages()   # my function
        }
```

In above function I need to use `this.listMessage` array in `this.renderMessages()` function.For that `getMessages()` function should execute my firestore query first and then `this.renderMessages()` function should be called.But without executing firestore query `this.renderMessages()` is being called.I know this is the issue with async / await functions but I don't know much about those functions.

Now how can I call `this.renderMessages()` function after the firestore query by using async / await functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type of approach for using async/await.

```
async function getMessage() {
 try {
 this.removeListener = await myFirestore
  .collection("messages")
  .doc(this.groupChatId)
  .collection(this.groupChatId)
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        this.listMessage.push(change.doc.data());
      }
    });
   });
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
return this.renderMessages();
}
```

The code above waits for myFirestore and then returns rendermessage. The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result. Hope this helps. If ypu want to catch error then you can use `try..catch` block

Comment: I didn't get it.Should I use this async function inside my getMessage() function?

Comment: No you should wrap a simple function with async function and use await keyword for things you want to blocking. This means your getMessage() function should be an async function.

Comment: I normally assign function to a constant but I have updated my code above.

Comment: It's not working.Your approach is working fine with normal functions but it's not waiting till firestore finishes its query.It is directly calling renderMessages() function.

Comment: Firestore function should return something